# Error Opening PGM file with PIL and SKIMAGE

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, scikit-image, pgm

I have following Image file:

[Image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0kpt8j4mby7vzsh/image_output.pgm?dl=0)

I used PIL and Skimage to open it but I get following errors

First with PIL (tried with and without trucate option):
Code:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFile
ImageFile.LOAD_TRUNCATED_IMAGES = True
img = Image.open("image_output.pgm")
```

Erorr:

```
OSError: cannot identify image file 'image_output.pgm'
```

And with Skimage:

Code:

```
from skimage import io
img = io.imread("image_output.pgm")
```

Error:

```
OSError: cannot identify image file <_io.BufferedReader name='image_output.pgm'>
```

I can open the file with GUI applications like system photo viewer and Matlab.

How can I diagnose what is wrong with image? I compared the byte data with other PGM files which I can open in Python, but could not identify the difference.

Thanks.

Comment: Your link seems not to work - please check it.

Comment: Also, you don't show your code for opening it.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I have fixed the image link and added the code. Please let me know if you can download the image. Also if you voted for "closing", please reconsider.

Comment: Close vote was not from me. Answer below :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file is `P2` type [PGM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm#Description), which means it is in ASCII - you can view it in a normal text editor. It seems neither **PIL**, nor **skimage** want to read that, but are happy to read the corresponding `P5` type which is identical except it is written in binary, rather than ASCII.

There are a few options...

---

1) You could use **OpenCV** to read it:

```
import cv2
im = cv2.imread('a.pgm')
```

---

2) You could convert it to `P5` with **ImageMagick** and then read the `output.pgm` file with **skimage** or **PIL**:

```
magick input.pgm output.pgm
```

---

3) If adding **OpenCV**, or **ImageMagick** as a dependency is a real pain for you, it is *possible* to read a PGM image yourself:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re
import numpy as np

# Open image file, slurp the lot
with open('input.pgm') as f:
   s = f.read()

# Find anything that looks like numbers
# Technically, there could be comments that should be ignored
l=re.findall(r'[0-9P]+',s)

# List "l" will contain: P5, width, height, 255, pixel1, pixel2, pixel3...
# Technically, if l[3]>255, you should change the type of the Numpy array to uint16, but that is not the case
w, h = int(l[1]), int(l[2])

# Make Numpy image from data
ni = np.array(l[4:],dtype=np.uint8).reshape((h,w))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I am on an institute machine and CV2 is not installed (I tried testing with it before posting, but could not). Also, I was about to install Imagemagick, but with 3rd option, I do not have to. Importantly, thank you for explanation.

Comment: Looks like an ultrasonic probe in an artery!

Comment: It is an output image for a medical imaging application, "SRAD", from "Axbench" benchmark suite. So, I am not an expert, but you must be right! Benchmark link: http://axbench.org/